# python missing parameter hints when override class with *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, autocomplete, type-hinting

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, agr1: str, arg2: int):
        """
        :param arg1: some tips 
        :param arg2: some tips 
        """
        pass

class Sub(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Here mybe override other methods

sub = Sub([here is no parameter hints])
```

In PyCharm, sub class has no parameter hints.

Is there a better way than copying all parameters in **init** from Parent to Sub?

Comment: Type hinting is meant to assist static analysis so the full typed parameters should be copied to facilitate that at the source level.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in this case. The only way to get your desired result would be to copy-paste the parameters from the `Parent` class to the `Sub` class.

Comment: Unless you pass to `Sub` exactly 2 arguments as positional and 0 as keyword, your code is gonna fail at runtime anyway. What is that you are trying to achieve here?